# How to deduce the sign changes?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, arithmetic-functions

Let $f$ be an arithmetical function. Suppose that there exists an integer set $A$ compromises the integers $n$ for which $f(n)>0$ and a set $B$ of integers $n$ such that $f(n)<0$ and a set $C$ compromises integers $n$ such that $f(n)=0$. Is there a result from number theory or an elementary result that allows us to determine the first sign changes of the sequence $(f(n))$ and to compute its number of sign changes in terms of element of the sets $A$ or $B$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that $A$ comprises **all** the $n$ such that $f(n) > 0$ and similarly for $B$?

Comment: @RobArthan yes I mean that.

Comment: You should edit you question to clarify that point. You may also like to consider the set $C$ says of integers where $f(x) = 0$. The sign changes occur when $n+1$ is in a different set from $n$.